# "Show all" for more than 200 items in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-admin, django-pagination

I currently have a listing in django admin that is split across 8 pages.

What I need to do is to have a button/link to display all items of a list in django admin even if there are more than 200 items while keeping the pagination.

**Show all** link does exactly what I need but it's limited to 200 items. Are there any ways to change it? (without modifying the core). Also, are there ways to change `list_per_page` in the modeladmin on demand?

Comment: i just found this http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1809/ but i am not sure where to put the code

Answer (score 22):

You can change the `list_max_show_all` and `list_per_page` attributes on your admin class.

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_max_show_all = 500
    list_per_page = 200
```

Works with Django 1.4 and newer. [See the manual.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_max_show_all)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you're looking for when you say "on demand" modification of list_per_page, but you could almost certainly query a database. It'd be rather unwieldy, but depending on your use case, administrators could log in, modify their preference, and then proceed to whatever model actually matters. 
For example:

```
#models.py
class PageLength(models.Model):
     page_length = models.IntegerField()

#admin.py

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_per_page = PageLength.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Show all** link appears if [list_max_show_all](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_max_show_all) value is more than or equal to total items while **Show all** link disappears if `list_max_show_all` value is less than total items. *`list_max_show_all` is 200 by default.

So, you need to set a higher value than `200` (Default) to `list_max_show_all` to show **Show all** link to list all items as shown below and you need to set [list_per_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_per_page) to list the specific number of items on each paginated **Change List** page. By default, `100` is set to `list_per_page`.

```py
# "admin.py"

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_max_show_all = 400 # Changes from 200 (Default) to 400  
    list_per_page = 300 # Changes from 100 (Default) to 300
```